# mongoDB filtering listCollections method

Tags: mongodb

Hello I would like to list all of the collections on my Mongodb except for two named "logos" and "outlets" but I can't seem to figure it out.

here is the code

```
db.listCollections({name: {$ne: 'outlets'}}, {name: {$ne: 'logos'}}).toArray((err, docs) => {
      console.log(docs)
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }

      assert.equal(err, null);

      return cb(null, docs);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(name => ['logos','outlets'].indexOf(name) === -1)
```

also in your query u can:

```
db.listCollections({name: {$nin: ['outlets', 'logos']}}).toArray(...)
```

If after all you need **find** or **aggregate**(or anything else) u can do this:

```
db.getCollection(YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME).find({})
```

to oversee the majority of teams MongoDB **you can install Robo 3T (Robomongo)**, there is a possibility to connect to servers

Comment: Perfect, the second solution solved my issue! Thank you so much!